# Pattern p= Pattern.compile("(?<!\\w)[tT]\\w+");

Tags: java, regex

please can any one help me to break this code and explain it to me

this code as shown in the title

i know the output of it but i want to know how it works

REGEX : `(?<!\\w)[tT]\\w+”)`

Comment: Learn Regular Expressions.

Comment: Take a look at this [site](http://regexone.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?<!\\w)[tT]\\w+
```

`(?<!\\w)`==>negative lookbehind (there should not be a [a-zA-Z0-9_] behind `t` or `T`.

`[tT]`======>`t` or `T`.

`\\w+`======>any [a-zA-Z0-9_]+.(should be one or more)

Basically it captures words like

`train`,`Train`,`@train`,`train`,`to`,`t121ka` etc.

It will not capture

`atrain`

Answer (score 2):

The parts of the regex are:

- `(?<!\\w)` = "the preceding char is not a "word" char
- `[tT]` = either "t" or "T"
- `\\w+` = "one or more "word" chars

Over all, it means "a word that starts with T and is at least 2 chars long"

Incidentally, this can be expressed more succinctly as:

```
\b[tT]\\w+
```

`\b` meaning "word boundary"